# Laravel polymorphic with custom foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, relationship

I have problem with custom shipmentable_type. My structure looks like this:

```
transfers:
id - integer
name - string

shipment:
id - integer
name - string

shipmentale:
shipment_id - integer
shipmentable_id - integer
shipmentabl_type - enum ( transfer, order, complaint, internet )
```

Now I have in my Transfer model realtion like this:

```
 public function shipments()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Shipment::class, 'shipmentable');
}
```

The problem is, that to table shipmentable, to column shipmentable_type is going sth like this now: App/Models/Transfer, but I would like to force to be there 'transfer' in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: Check out Custom Polymorphic Types https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)

> By default, Laravel will use the fully qualified class name to store the type of the related model. However, you may wish to decouple your database from your application's internal structure. In that case, you may define a relationship "morph map" to instruct Eloquent to use a custom name for each model instead of the class name:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation;

Relation::morphMap([
   'transfer' => 'App/Models/Transfer'
]);
```

You may register the `morphMap` in the `boot` function of your `AppServiceProvider` or create a separate service provider if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

To set a value other than the model's fully qualified name in `shipmentable_type`, there is the `Relation::morphMap()` function.

```
Relation::morphMap([
    'transfer' => 'App/Models/Transfer'
]);
```

This should be set in the `AppServiceProvider` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue but unfortunately I had multiple models pointing at `transfer` with multiple locations. You can resolve them dynamically on your model:

```
class Transfers extends Model
{
    /**
     * Declare the class to get connect polymorphic relationships.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    protected $morphClass = null;

    /**
     * Get the associated morph class.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getMorphClass()
    {
        return $this->morphClass ?: static::class;
    }

    public function shipments()
    {
        $this->morphClass = 'transfer';
        return $this->morphToMany(Shipment::class, 'shipmentable');
    }

    // ...
}
```